# Refit AliasAs does not work for deserialize

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, refit

Just wonder what is the proper way to use AliasAs in deserializing a response in ReFit?  The code below will correctly parse a response if the variable name in the model is the same as in the response, but the returned value will be null if the names are different.

Model class:

```
using Refit;
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace TestRefit
{
    public class PriceModel
    {
        [AliasAs("disclaimer")]
        public string? Disclaimer123 { get; set; } 
        // "Disclaimer" or "disclaimer" work, but not "DisclaimerWhatever", "Disclaimer123", ....

        [AliasAs("charName")]
        public string? ChartName { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Interface class:

```
using Refit;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestRefit
{
    public interface IPrice
    {
        [Get("/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")]
        Task<PriceModel> GetPrice();
    }
}
```

Invocation:

```
public async void LoadPrice()
{
    var iPriceClient = RestService.For<IPrice>("https://api.coindesk.com");
    CurPrice = await iPriceClient.GetPrice();
    Debug.WriteLine($"**** Check: {CurPrice?.ChartName}, {CurPrice?.Disclaimer123}.");
    // Output: **** Check: Bitcoin, . 
    return;
}
```

I found this article https://github.com/reactiveui/refit/issues/450 .  Has anything changed since?  By the way, older version of Refit that uses the NewSoftJson equivalence [JsonProperty] seems to work without any problem.

Answer (score 6):

Refit provides 2 implementations out of the box. The default is the `SystemTextJsonContentSerializer` from `System.Text.Json`. The alternative implementation is `NewtonsoftJsonContentSerializer` which comes from `Newtonsoft.Json`. [You can read here how to setup Refit Newtonsoft](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit#json-content)

So in order to deserialize your response you should decide which one to use first.

If you decide to use `SystemTextJsonContentSerializer` from `System.Text.Json` you should use the `[JsonPropertyName("YourJsonPropertyNameHere")]` attribute [as you can read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0#customize-individual-property-names)

If end up using `NewtonsoftJsonContentSerializer` from `Newtonsoft.Json` you should use the `[JsonProperty("YourJsonPropertyNameHere")]`. [More on the JsonPropertyAttribute can be read here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm)

Comment: Changing AliasAs to JsonPropertyName is what helped me.